# How to make a way to interact with a 3D model in different ways? (Make it rotate and light up)

Tags: objects, workflow

My goal is to make a program where I can interact with a model based on a Concept Modelling Language - rotate it, to view it from every angle and make certain parts of it light up when I click on it.

If any of you could provide me with a list of what I need to learn in as much detail as possible, I would be immensely grateful!

I already know how to model and texture, but that's about it.

Answer (score 2):

The Blend4Web extension should be able to do a lot of the work for you. In a few steps you can have a live web display of your model allowing you to rotate, pan, zoom. Adding interactivity such as lighting up is possible too, but requires more work.

https://www.blend4web.com/en/demo/

Answer (score 0):

For making the cube interactive, I don't know how to do that.
But I know how to make certain parts of the cube light up.
Here are the steps:

1. Change the Diffuse to a color of your choice.
2. Scroll down to "Shading" and change "Emit" to any number.
3. Press `Tab` to enter Edit mode.
4. Select the faces that you would like to light up.
5. Go to "Material" and make another material that is grey.
6. Click "Assign" (like in picture) and the selected face will become gray. 
   [image: clicking assign]
   That's it!

You get something like this:
[image: all done!]

Hope this helps!